# RTSP player performance

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-mediaplayer, gstreamer, rtsp

I am struggling with rtsp playing performance i tried android mediaplayer to play the rtsp link but the delay is about 5 second. Then i came to know about Gstreamer and ffmpeg i have started exploring the gstreamer library to create a rtsp player there is a post on android which says that you can get the performance of <500ms delay.

So is there is any work done on android to acheive that performance or i have to create it by myself

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this ffmpeg to android](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/comment-page-2/) solution. At the bottom of the page you will find link to the tutorials with simple implementation. After some minor edits you should be able to get playback with delay <500 ms.

Comment: are you sure you share the correct link i didn't see any sample project  there

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. [Here](https://github.com/roman10/android-ffmpeg-tutorial) is the tutorial project which you can find at the bottom of the compile guide.

Comment: BTW do you have personal experience with this, i mean playring rtsp using ffmpeg

Comment: Yes. Besides the above configuration, I am using ffserver to stream rtsp and I get quite a small delay with it.

Comment: okay i will give it a hit and get back to you, in case of any issue.

Comment: Right now i am working on gstream too. So may b i can get my thing done with this

Comment: Cool. If you manage to get decent delays pls let me know that it's possible

Comment: I am able to run rtsp link throught gstreamer but it has a delay of 2.2 sec.

Comment: Nothing special. I don't know much about gstreamer but try to find out if your app buffers some frames before displaying them